# Does Summoning: Impure World Resurrection automatically equip the reincarnated shinobi?

Tags: naruto

For example, when Kinkaku and Ginkaku are reincarnated, they have their ninja tools. It is also the case with the reincarnated Seven Ninja Swordsmen.

If this is so, suppose someone else had acquired one of the ninja tools, would there be two copies of the tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be only one copy of the tool at a time. The resurrected shinobi get their tools if they have not been acquired by others in the real world.

When the Seven legendary swordsmen were summoned, initially only Zabuza had his Kubikiribōchō. Although Suigetsu had acquired it, it was taken away from him when he was arrested at the five Kage meeting. Thus, it seems the Edo Tensei transferred it to Zabuza.

[image: Suigetsu looking for his sword]

Later, Mangetsu summons 4 other swords from his scroll. He had presumably sealed them in his scroll before he died, which is probably why they were not acquired by others.

The only swords missing are the Samehada and Hiramekarei, which were in possession of Bee and Chojuro respectively. Similarly, Sasori did not get his puppets, because Kankuro had taken their possession.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any info on how Kinkaku and Ginkaku got their tools? Or can we infer that Kabuto must have obtained them somehow?

Comment: I think they got their tools just like how Zabuza got his sword. The Kohaku no Jōhei (Amber Purifying Pot) was the only one in the Fourth Raikage's possession, and thus Kinkaku and Ginkaku did not have it when they were revived. The other tools they used were not taken over by someone else in the living world after they died, and thus were available to them.

Comment: If Suigetsus Sword was taken away, that means, that someone else possessed it. Wouldn't it be more logical, that Kabuto possessed the sword and gave it to Zabuza, instead of Edo Tensei?

Comment: @looper It is a good point, but it is highly unlikely that Kabuto infiltrated the room where the sword was kept just to get that sword. It was just left unattended in that room (see picture), which meant it was not in anyone's possession per se. Or maybe his "upgraded" Edo Tensei allows him to control real world objects through the revived shinobi, and he decided not to bother getting the swords held by Bee and Chojuro. Again, this is speculation.

Comment: From what I recall, Kinkaku took their tools from his mouth. This could mean that they were somehow sealed with some special jutsu, something like the way Gerotora was once inside Jiraiya's stomach and then inside Naruto's.

Comment: looper and JNat, Thanks for those points! I had missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Kinkaku and Ginkaku had the weapons sealed inside them, much like Orochimaru produces his sword from his mouth.

Comment: When was that told? When was it shown that the artifacts come out of their bodies? I don't remember that. Do you have any evidence to support your claim?