# Can a reanimated Rinnegan user use the Outer Path to revive someone?

Tags: naruto

The reanimated Nagato used the Six Paths Techniques while fighting Naruto and Killerbee. When Madara was reanimated, he thought he had been revived by Nagato as planned. Can Kabuto or Tobi not make Nagato use the Rinnegan's Outer Path to revive someone, such as Madara, so that they would not need to use the Edo Tensei on him?

Please disregard the fact that Kabuto wanted to control Madara, so he had to reanimated him using Edo Tensei.

Comment: If thats the case, why not let reincarnated lady chio to revive Madara using reanimation jutsu (the justsu she used on gaara) ?

Comment: @Happy you are needed here :-)

Comment: I think you did stumble upon one of the many plot holes here though. In order to revive someone, you are supposed to use the Rinnegan. Obito took Nagato's eyes out and yet he came back with them. Yet there was another instance when someone came back lacking a weapon (I can't remember who, but I think it was a sword). Sometimes people come back with their possessions and sometimes people don't.

Comment: @krikara That's not a plot hole. Nagato's eyes are a part of his body, the sword is not. If you stretch it a bit, Edo Tensei itself is a plot hole, because the dead person's corpse is (usually) destroyed, so none of their body parts should return.

Comment: But then by that logic, we can spawn infinite Rinnegans. And we don't need a dead person's corpse to use Edo Tensei, we have plenty of Zetsus :D It just doesn't make sense that some things return and not others.

Comment: @krikira Related: 
[Does Summoning: Impure World Resurrection automatically equip the reincarnated shinobi?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/1970/99), [Is it possible to duplicate eyes?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2024/99)

Comment: @krikara Yes, absolutely. Right now, we see Obito and Madara both using Rinnegan, and if things had gone differently, Edo Tensei Nagato might have been still around with his Rinnegan, though they are all just Madara's Rinnegan.

Comment: @RikuduSennin, I think on Chio's technique requires the own life force of the user, thus making her incapable of using such technique since she is an Edo Tensei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reanimated Nagato can use the Outer Path to revive someone. Kabuto was even planning to make use of this to capture Naruto and Bee, without letting Tobi know.

Chapter 551 shows that Kabuto's plan was to have Nagato temporarily kill Naruto and Bee by pulling their souls with Ningendo (Human Path), then hide their souls and bodies with the Jigokudo (Naraka Path), have Nagato come to Kabuto's hideout, where he can revive them using the Outer Path. (See image below.)

He doesn't use it on Madara, because he won't be able to control Madara if revived through Edo Tensei, as you mentioned. 
[image: Kabuto plans to capture Naruto and Bee using Nagato]

Comment: Thats it, I forgot about Kabuto's plan with Naruto and Bee. So there is a way to repeatedly use Rinnegan's Outer path to fully revive someone.

Comment: Actually, Madara also ask Nagato through Obito to summon him using the Outer path of the Rinnegan. But since Nagato is dead, Obito would likely use the Edo Tensei Nagato.