# Nagato's Eye in Edo tensei Mode

Tags: naruto

After seeing this discussion [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/can-a-reanimated-rinnegan-user-use-the-outer-path-to-revive-someone?rq=1), I think how come Edo-tensei nagato had rinnegan. Nagato's original eyes were normal. He received rinnegan from madara. So his edo tensei form should have had normal eyes not rinnegan, if edo tensei brings the original soul; because his eyes were normal until madara gave him his rinnegan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when a person is brought back by Edo Tensei, that person is revived from the last "checkpoint" of his life, when they were at their strongest. Even if originally Nagato's eyes weren't the Rinnegan, when he died he possessed it, similar to Itachi having a full potential Mangekyo Sharingan, yet he was blinded prior to his death in the last moment of his fight with Sasuke.

Since no other Uchiha was resurrected, nor other Rinnegan user was revived, this could be the only possible conclusion you can deduct from these shinobi (if you don't calculate to be a plot hole), that you're coming back from the time when you had your full strength. For example, look at Madara: he is in his younger ages, not an old grandpa who was shown in the cave with Obito.

Comment: But then, how would explain Madara's revival possessing Rinnegan? He only got those eyes when he was quite old.

Comment: kinda' combination of the best age with the best skills maybe??...theory

Comment: or maybe just coincidence,because in the filler parts(that old man with sunglasses) and granny Chiyo too was resurrected at the age they'we died...so i guess the it's random,someone is revived just like he was prior to his/her death and others will resurrect younger,yet with all of the abilities, which were accumulated along his life

Comment: Madara being revived in his prime were the doings of Kabuto. If I recollect properly, when Kabuto brought Madara to the battlefield, he did mention that he had a surprise in store for him and that was his revival in his prime. Edo Tensei brings back people in their alive state with Madara being the exception because of Kabuto's doings.

Comment: still,this doesn't explain that little detail,which I've been mentioning earlier...don't forget,that after the Rinne tensei, Nagato's hair got hoary,and he was resurrected with that "greyish" hair,but in Itachi's case, he got resurrected  with his mangekyo,and not being blind...and if i recall well,Madara was resurrected with 2 eyes,and prior to his death he's got one...everywhere it's complicated with those eyes:)))

Comment: may be a plot hole. kishi didn't plan this perfectly. as you said while itachi got mangekyo while he was dead, nagato got something which wasn't his. also the young madara.

Comment: @Sp0T Note these rinnegan were Fake Rinnegan, and did not have the full power of real ones. They could not be used to Summon the Gedo Mazo, and presumably had other limits as well. I do not recall exactly where that was stated, but a major part of the proof is that Madara's Rinnegan turned to dust when he was revived, and he had to get his real eyes back.