# How does Edo Tensei Madara get back his Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

Madara gave his Rinnegan to Nagato. But after Kabuto brings him back using Edo Tensei, he still has the Rinnegan. How is this possible?

Comment: When Edo Tensei Madara appeared on the battlefield, Kabuto (in Mū's body) tells that he modified Madara's body to reflect his prime state. Which includes physical prime from his youth, wisdom and memory till his age of death, Hashirama implants, etc. These are the in-story details that support the Rinnegan in ET Madara

Comment: Same happen to Itachi , related question [Nagato's Eye in Edo tensei Mode](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/nagatos-eye-in-edo-tensei-mode)

Comment: Reincarnation technique gives the user all their abilities, every single one they ever had. (thanks to 2nd Hokage and damn Orochimaru!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Narutopedia:

> **A reincarnated individual will have all the abilities they had during their life, including kekkei genkai and kekkei tōta.** They are psychically restored as they were at the time of their death, including any physical handicaps they may have possessed, such as Nagato's damaged legs.

Since Madara had the Rinnegan when he died, he is resurrected with it again (with the help of Kabuto's modifications, if you remember).

However, the Edo Tensei Rinnegans are fake. Although Edo Tensei Madara can use them to absorb ninjutsu, he can't use it to summon the Gedo Mazo, or use Limbo. It's kinda the same with Nagato's Rinnegan or Itachi's Mangekyo Sharingan.

For further proof, when Madara was revived in flesh through Rinne Rebirth, he lost his fake Rinnegan.

Comment: Just a small correction, he didn't revive with the Rinnegan because of Kabuto's modifications. He would have been Edo Tensei revived with it regardless because he had it when he died. Kabuto's "modifications" revived Madara with his youthful, most powerful body instead of the old and frail one he died in.

Answer (score -2):

Actually Madara didn't give Nagato the Rinnegan,he only awakened it in him,and as he was an Uzumaki (which are distant relatives of Senju),he was able to control it.Madara got the Rinnegan by merging Hashirama's cells with his heart,awakening his Rinnegan very late in his life,after which he shortly died.That is why,when he was resurrected he had the Rinnegan.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that? I thought madara gave the rinnegan to Nagato so that he could use it to bring madara back to life.

Comment: Madara flat out said he gave his rinnegan to "someone" while talking to obito, and he only had one regular sharingan eye. Before he did that, he summoned the Gedo mazo and extended his life until he chose to die, leaving everything to obito.

Comment: Yeah, but Nagato has two rinegans not only one, and he awakened in chieldhood, so is not Madara's rinegan

Comment: @Rezende Nagato has only one rinnegan

Comment: Nagato had two Rinnegan eyes, which was transplanted by Madara when Nagato was just a child. The Rinnegan was indeed Madara's.

Comment: Yes, thats it, Two by Madara